# Merge two XSLT into one to process the same nodes for two different reasons

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I want to remove all namespaces (including all xmlns & xsi from attributes) and then want to sort the output.

Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"
xmlns:f="https://www.w3schools.com/furniture" xmlns='http://ns.xyz.org/2004-08-02'
xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
xmlns:ns1='http://ns.xyz.org/2004-08-02'
xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
xsi:type='ns1:table'>

    <h:table>
        <h:tr>
            <!-- <TestComment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/> -->
            <h:td att2="2" att1="1">Bananas</h:td>
            <h:td xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true">Apples</h:td>
        </h:tr>
    </h:table>

    <f:table>
        <f:name class="1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true">African Coffee Table</f:name>
        <f:width>80</f:width>
        <f:length>120</f:length>
    </f:table>
</root>
```

Right now I am transforming the xml in two different xsls.

XSL to remove namespaces (including xmlns & xsi) is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@xsi:*" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
<xsl:template match="comment()|processing-instruction()"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives me the following output

```
<root>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td att2="2" att1="1">Bananas</td>
            <td>Apples</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <name class="1">African Coffee Table</name>
        <width>80</width>
        <length>120</length>
    </table>
</root>
```

And then I use the below xsl to sort the xml

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
                <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
                <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
                <xsl:sort select="."/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives me the final output as

```
<root>
    <table>
        <length>120</length>
        <name class="1">African Coffee Table</name>
        <width>80</width>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Apples</td>
            <td att1="1" att2="2">Bananas</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</root>
```

Now, how do I merge these two processing into one xsl file so that I don't have to transform twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the two `xsl:sort` into the namespace removing templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@xsi:*" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
<xsl:template match="comment()|processing-instruction()"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
            <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
          <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
          <xsl:sort select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/jyyiVhg

Or use two modes to separate processing steps and perform the first step in a variable, then use `exsl:node-set` to process it with the second step/mode.